# `UPDATE ... WHERE ... ` multiple rows locking in InnoDB

Tags: mysql, innodb

I'm implementing a custom table-based sequence generator for MySQL database v5.7.16 with InnoDB engine.
The `sequence_table` looks as follows:

```
+-------------+-----------+
|sequence_name|next_value |
+-------------+-----------+
|  first_seq  |     1     |
+-------------+-----------+
|  second_seq |     1     |
+-------------+-----------+
```

`sequence_name` column is a primary key.
This sequence table contains multiple sequences for different consumers.

I use the following strategy for the sequence updates:

1. Select current sequence value: `select next_val from sequence_table where sequence_name=?`.
2. Add the allocation size to current sequence value.
3. Update the sequence value if it's current value matches the value selected in the first step: `update sequence_table set next_val=? where sequence_name=? and next_val=?`.
4. If the update is successful return the increased sequence value, otherwise repeat the process from step 1.

The documentation contains the following information:

> UPDATE ... WHERE ... sets an exclusive next-key lock on every record
>   **the search encounters**. However, only an index record lock is required
>   for statements that lock rows using a unique index to search for a
>   unique row. [14.5.3 Locks Set by Different SQL Statements in InnoDB](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locks-set.html)

The part in bold is a bit confusing.
As you can see, I match the primary key in the `WHERE` clause of the `UPDATE` statement.

Is it possible that the search may encounter more than one record and therefore lock multiple rows in this sequence table?

In other words, will the update in the 3rd step of the algorithm block just one or multiple rows?

Comment: As I understand from reading [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking.html#innodb-next-key-locks), it would lock multiple rows. I also believe that you can control the behavior through [Isolation Levels](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html).

Comment: Are you trying to re-create `auto_increment` without so-called gaps?

Comment: @flip, `next-key lock locks only one index record and the gap before it`. It's an expected behavior and since I don't insert anything regularly into this table this will mean that next-key lock will lock only one index record (=one row) during the update. But the searching part is unclear for me.

Comment: @N.B., the application code needs to have a possibility to decide which sequence to use to get next value, `auto_increment` doesn't fit my needs. In PostgreSQL I'd just have two sequences to accomplish this.

Comment: You are going to have SUCH a bad time. I didn't want to imply you should use `auto_increment`. Best of luck, for real.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't mention what transaction isolation level you're planning to use. 
Lets assume you're using `repeatable read` (in `read committed` no such a problem should exist)

From [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html):

> For locking reads (SELECT with FOR UPDATE or LOCK IN SHARE MODE),
>   UPDATE, and DELETE statements, locking depends on whether the
>   statement uses a unique index with a unique search condition, or a
>   range-type search condition

and

> For a unique index with a unique search condition, InnoDB locks only
>   the index record found, not the gap before it

So at least in theory it should lock only a single record and no next-key lock will be used.

More quotes from other docs pages to back my thoughts:

#### innodb-next-key-locks

[link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking.html#innodb-next-key-locks)

> A next-key lock is a combination of a record lock on the index record
>   and a gap lock on the gap before the index record.

#### gap locks

[link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking.html#innodb-gap-locks)

> Gap locking is not needed for statements that lock rows using a unique
>   index to search for a unique row

Answer (score 0):

- Don't grab the sequence numbers inside the main transaction; do it *before* the `START TRANSCTION`.
- Do the task in a single statement with `autocommit=ON`.

Both of those lead to it being much faster, less likely to block.

(You code was missing `BEGIN/COMMIT` and `FOR UPDATE`.  I got rid of those rather than explaining the issues.)

Set up test:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE so49197964 (
    ->     name VARCHAR(22) NOT NULL,
    ->     next_value INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    ->     PRIMARY KEY (name)
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO so49197964 (name, next_value)
    ->     VALUES
    ->     ('first', 1), ('second', 1);
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM so49197964;
+--------+------------+
| name   | next_value |
+--------+------------+
| first  |          1 |
| second |          1 |
+--------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Grab 20 nums from 'first' and fetch the starting number:

```
mysql> UPDATE so49197964
    ->     SET next_value = LAST_INSERT_ID(next_value) + 20
    ->     WHERE name = 'first';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
+------------------+
| LAST_INSERT_ID() |
+------------------+
|                1 |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM so49197964;
+--------+------------+
| name   | next_value |
+--------+------------+
| first  |         21 |
| second |          1 |
+--------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Grab another 20:

```
mysql> UPDATE so49197964
    ->     SET next_value = LAST_INSERT_ID(next_value) + 20
    ->     WHERE name = 'first';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
+------------------+
| LAST_INSERT_ID() |
+------------------+
|               21 |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM so49197964;
+--------+------------+
| name   | next_value |
+--------+------------+
| first  |         41 |
| second |          1 |
+--------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```